# Ubuntu OpenVPN with Grandstream GXP2130

Tags: openvpn

I have an openvpn server setup on Ubuntu server 16.04 and i imported client config into a Grandstream gxp 2130 phone however when the vpn is connected, the client still appear from its original public IP address but I want it to appear from VPN's public IP. Could anyone advise me what needs to be done?

Network diagram:

[image: Network diagram]

How to route the traffic To get out of the OpenVPN server so the SIP traffic appear from Y.Y.Y.Y public IP address?

Comment: If you confirmed the VPN is working, how to configure the SIP phone to use it is a question for your user's manual and/or tech support. It's not a question about Ubuntu.

Comment: Thanks CelticWorrior for the quick response, I have added a diagram to show the network, the ISP on my side that does poor NAT thus the SIP traffic is hit and miss. That is why I need to pass the SIP and RTP traffic though the VPN tunnel. I would assume that by IP tables and static routes it should be possible.